# Proof: Determinant of a block matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, block-matrices

My homework is due tomorrow (12h left), that means I've already lost, but I'm looking genuinely for a possible solution.

The Problem:

> Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $1 \leq r \leq n$. Let $A = [a_{ij}]_{i,j}$ be an $r \times r$ matrix, let $B = [b_{ij}]_{i,j}$ be an $r \times (n-r)$ - matrix, and let $C = [c_{ij}]_{i,j}$ be an $(n - r) \times (n-r)$ matrix. We define an $n \times n$ matrix
>
> $$D = [d_{ij}]_{i,j} := \left[\begin{array}{c|c}
>   A & B \\
>   \hline
>   0 & C
>  \end{array}\right].$$
>
> Show that: $det(D) = det(A) \cdot det(C)$.
>
> Further, distinguish between the cases when $C$ is invertible and when $C$ is not invertible.

To be sincere: I don't even have a solution approach.

Comment: It's an easy consequence of Joriki's great answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75293/determinant-of-a-block-lower-triangular-matrix). I feel like this is is good enough to close as duplicate.

Comment: Please click "Edit" and familiarize yourself with the formating, so that you do it properly the next time.