# Determinant of block-triangular matrix made of 3 matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

> 3. Let $A$ be a $k \times k$ matrix and $B$ be a $\left(n-k\right) \times \left(n-k\right)$ matrix, and $Z$ be the $n \times n$ matrix
>      $$ Z = \left( \begin{matrix} A & C \\ 0 & B \end{matrix} \right),$$
>      where $C$ is any $k \times \left(n-k\right)$ matrix. Show that
>      $$\det Z = \det A \cdot \det B.$$

So I understand this in my head. I get the det(Z)=det(A)det(B)-det(C)(0). I am having trouble figuring out how to prove this though. There may be some theorem that I am missing or something. Any tips or leads would be helpful though.

Comment: Would det(**AB**)=det(**A**)det(**B**) be related?

Comment: "det(Z)=det(A)det(B)-det(C)(0)" is not the right way to go. If there was a fourth matrix $D$ instead of $0$, then you would *not* generally have $\det Z = \det A \cdot \det B - \det C \cdot \det D$. Anyway this is a well-known result, and I hope someone answers it nicely to have a reference for the future generations...

Comment: $\det \left(AB\right) = \det A \cdot \det B$ holds when $A$ and $B$ are of the same size, which they here are not necessarily.

Comment: You can see some general rules about block matrices here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Block_matrices.

Comment: And here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75293/determinant-of-a-block-lower-triangular-matrix, there is a possible duplicate of your question.