# Finding the determinant of a block matrix (Linear Algebra)

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$, $B$ be $n$ by $n$ matrices. Let $0$ be the all zero matrix of size $n$. Show that

$$\det\left[\begin{array}[cc]\\A& 0\\
0&B\end{array}\right]=\det(A)\det(B)$$

What i tried

What i tried was first letting $A$ and $B$ be a simple 2 by 2 matrix and observing how the determinant relate to each other and then working my up. WHat i can deduce is that, if $A$ is singular than this will maake both sides of the equation $0$ hence proving the equation. Im currently working on the case when $A$ is not singular Could anyone explain. Thanks

Comment: What definition of the determinant do you use?

Comment: Induction on the number of row operations needed to get the big matrix into upper-triangular form.

Comment: What i tried was first letting $A$ and $B$ be a simple 2 by 2 matrix by observing how the determinant relate to each other and then working my up. WHat i can deduce is that, if $A$ is singular than this will maake both sides of the equation $0$ hence proving the equation. Im still working on the case when $A$ is not singular

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75293/determinant-of-a-block-lower-triangular-matrix