# characteristic polynomial of matrix with several blocks

Tags: matrices, block-matrices, characteristic-polynomial

$\mathbf{M}=\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{y}&0&0&\cdots&0&0&\mathbf{x}\\
\mathbf{I}&0&0&\cdots&0&0&0\\
0&\mathbf{I}&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&\mathbf{I}&0&0&0&0\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots\\
0&0&0&\cdots&\mathbf{I}&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&\mathbf{I}&0\\
\end{bmatrix}$

Given that $\mathbf{y}=\operatorname{diag}\left(y_i\right)$ and $\mathbf{x}=\operatorname{diag}\left(x_i\right) $ where each $i=1,2,\dots, N$, $y_i$ are $N\times N$ matrices whose eigenvalues are strictly less inside unit circle. $I$ are $N\times N$. For each $i$, $x_i$ are also $N\times N$   Could anyone tell me what would be the characterstic polynomial of $\mathbf{M}$? Thanks.

I was trying the technique [a block matrix proof about characteristic polynomials](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2395133/a-block-matrix-proof-about-characteristic-polynomials#2395162) but could not proceed much.

Also, does taking the transpose of $M$ help?

Comment: I can't make the dimensions work. You say the $I$ are $N\times N$. So $y$ has $N$ columns. But you also say $y$ is diagonal with $n$ blocks of size $N\times N$ along the diagonal. Can you clarify?

Comment: Oops sorry, everything is $N$ here. You are right.

Comment: I still don't understand your question. As written, if $I$ is $N\times N$ then $y$ has $N$ columns. You then say that $y$ is a diagonal of $N$ blocks $y_i$. This forces the $y_i$ to have $1$ column each. But then you say $y_i$ is $N\times N$. So $N$ must be $1$.  I'm sure you don't mean that? So please edit the question again.

Comment: Come one each $y_i$ is $N\times N$  matrix so $\mathbf{y}$ is a block diagonal matrix right?

Comment: Tell me: what are the dimensions of (i) the matrix $y$ (ii) the matrix $y_1$?

Comment: $y$ is $N^2\times N^2$ and $y_i$ are $N\times N$

Comment: So if $y$ is $N^2\times N^2$ how big is the $I$ just below it? It can't be $N\times N$ unless $N=1$>

Comment: $0$ are also block of $N\times N$ $I$ are also N\times N$

Comment: Look: you write this as a big block matrix, and  now you tell me that the blocks you show don't match in size. As I keep saying $I$ and $y$ must have the *same* number of columns.

Comment: Then $I$ is $N^2\times N^2$, is that fine now?

Comment: If you make the $I$ and the $0$ $N^2 \times N^2$ then the question makes sense. (Though it looks hard). You should also specify the size of $M$, something like $(k+1)N^2$.

Comment: On the other hand, what would be a simpler dimension which you think can solve the problem? Thanks so much for your help

Comment: At present I can do $N=1,k=0$ and not much more. ;-) I will think.