# Determinant of a matrix in a block form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, matrix-calculus

Let $A, B, C$ be matrices with size $m \times m$,  $n \times n$, and $n \times m$, respectively. If $\det(A) = 2$ and $\det(B) = 3,$ then find
$$\det \begin{pmatrix} 0 & A \\ B & C \end{pmatrix} =\ldots $$

I stuck to solve this problem. I also wonder how can we calculate a determinant of matrix with some matrices in it (submatrices)? 
Please, anyone help me

Comment: Search for determinant of block matrices, there are plenty of relevant posts here. Like this one:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75293/determinant-of-a-block-lower-triangular-matrix?noredirect=1&lq=1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints.

Step 1.
$$
\det \left(\begin{array}{cc} 0 & A \\ B & C\end{array}\right)
=(-1)^m\det \left(\begin{array}{cc} A & 0 \\ C & B\end{array}\right)
$$

Step 2.
$$
\det \left(\begin{array}{cc} A & 0 \\ C & B\end{array}\right)=\det A\cdot \det B
$$

Step 1, is obtained by $m^2$ permutations of rows and as many changes of sign.

Step 2, is obtained using the Jordan forms of $A$ and $B$.

Comment: What about if the matrix (which contain block matrices) is not triangular? Can we calculate the determinant?

Comment: @ShaneDizzySukardy There exist certain tricks. Nevertheless, most of them for special matrices. For example, if all blocks are square of the same size, you can imitate the treatment of the $2\times 2$ case.