# How to prove $\det(I_m+AA^t)=\det(I_n+A^tA)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

> Let $A \in M_{m \times n}({\Bbb F})$, prove $$ \det\left(I_m + AA^t\right) = \det\left(I_n + A^tA\right) $$

---

I don't need the full answer, maybe a hint. I've tried using Sylvester's identity but I can't solve either way. I tried to replicate the proof from [here](https://users.math.yale.edu/%7Eauel/courses/370f06/docs/solutions1.pdf), but I wondered if there were other proofs, that is why I asked for a hint, this is not homework.

Comment: Hint: Singular values.

Comment: We haven't cover such topic, we are trying to use properties of the determinant as a alternating $n-$linear function.

Comment: Put $A, A^T$ and $I$ into a larger matrix as blocks, use invertible transformations on this large matrix, and then take the determinant.

Comment: $det |I+AA^t|= det |(I+AA^t)^t|=det |I+A^t A|$

Comment: @DrZafarAhmedDSc $(I+AA^t)^t=I+AA^t$.

Comment: The link is broken

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a sketch. Assume without loss of generality that $m < n$. Writing $A = A' \oplus 0$ (over some basis) with $A'\in M_{m\times m}$, reduce to the case of $m = n$. If $A$ is invertible, then 
$$\det (1 + AA^t) = \det A(A^{-1} + A^t) = \det(A^t) \det ((A^{-1})^t + A)^t = \det(1 + A^t A).$$
But the given equation is a polynomial in $A_{ij}$, and the space of invertible $A$ is dense.

Comment: I didn't understand the last line, why worry to say such $A$ is dense?

Comment: We assumed that $A$ is invertible midway through the proof sketch. The displayed equation doesn't make sense otherwise; but the result holds for general $A$ if it holds for invertible $A$ by continuity.

Answer (score 3):

For square matrices, take determinant on both sides of 
$$\begin{pmatrix}I&0\\A^T&I\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}I+AA^T&A\\0&I\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}I&0\\-A^T&I\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}I&A\\0&I+A^TA\end{pmatrix}$$
For non-square matrices you can pad it with zeros to a square matrix and use the formula above.

Comment: Good solution, but it might be worth to mention that the block triangular determinants are not entirely trivial (except when the matrix is indeed triangular). See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75293/determinant-of-a-block-lower-triangular-matrix