# Prove $\det(M)=\det(A)\det(B)$ by induction

Tags: linear-algebra, induction, determinant

Prove by mathematical induction on the size of matrix A that

$\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
&\operatorname{If} M \in M_{n \times n}(K) \text { and } A \text { y } B \text { are square } M=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
A & 0 \\
0 & B
\end{array}\right] \text { then }\\
&\det (M)=\det(A)\det(B)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}$

I try this

If A is a Matrix $1\times1$ then $\det(M)=\det(\begin{bmatrix}
A & 0 \\
0 & B
\end{bmatrix})=a_1\det(B)=\det(A)*\det(B)$

If A is a Matrix $2\times2$ then $\det(M)=\det(\begin{bmatrix}
A & 0 \\
0 & B
\end{bmatrix})=a_1\det(\begin{bmatrix}
A_{11} & 0 \\
0 & B
\end{bmatrix})+(-1)^{3}a_2\det(\begin{bmatrix}
A_{12} & 0 \\
0 & B
\end{bmatrix})=a_1a_4\det(B)-a_2a_3\det(B)=\det(B)(a_1a_4-a_2a_3)=\det(B)\det(A)$

Then I suppose is true for a matrix $n\times n$ with a matrix $A_{s\times s}$
and this is where I'm stuck to prove it is valid for a matrix $A_{s+1\times s+1}$

Comment: Non-inductive proofs galore: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75293/determinant-of-a-block-lower-triangular-matrix

Comment: For an inductive proof, see the solution to Exercise 6.29 in [my *Notes on the combinatorial fundamentals of algebra*](http://www.cip.ifi.lmu.de/~grinberg/primes2015/sols.pdf). It's a rather boring argument and not easy to summarize in a quick hint. The best I can do is "expand $\det M$ along the first row, and realize that this boils down to the same as expanding $\det A$ along the first row".

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ is $n_1\times n_1$ and $B$ is $n_2\times n_2$ then $\begin{pmatrix}A&0\\0&B\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}A&0\\0&I_{n_2}\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}I_{n_1}&0\\0&B\end{pmatrix}$

What you showed for $1\times 1$ matrix just extends to $I_n$ of any size (very straightforward induction).
So the determinant of the first matrix is $\det(A)$ and for the second one $\det(B)$.

Then use $\det(XY)=\det(X)\det(Y)$ property.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Expand along the first row.

Comment: The user who voted to delete this answer cannot expand along the first row?

Comment: I did this $\begin{equation}
det(M)=\sum_{j=1}^{s+m+1}(-1)^{1+j} a_{1 j} det(M_{1j}) 
\end{equation} $ = $\begin{equation}
det(M)=\sum_{j=1}^{s+m+1}(-1)^{1+j} a_{1 j} det(A_{1j}det(B))
\end{equation}$ = $detAdetB$ is this right?

Comment: Yes, that is right.

Comment: There is a ")" missing. And before the last "=" you should take $\det B$ outside the $\Sigma$.